# Do Realm writes cascade?

Tags: swift, realm

*I'm currently using Realm Swift 1.0.1.*

Say you have a Realm `Object`, that has another Realm `Object` as a property, like so:

```
import RealmSwift

class Car: Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    dynamic var model = ""
}

class Garage: Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    dynamic var carStored: Car?
}
```

If you then create new `Car` and `Garage` objects, with the `Car` being a property of the `Garage`... but only write the new `Garage` to the `Realm`, like so...

```
let teslaCar = Car()
teslaCar.id = 1
teslaCar.model = "Tesla"

let myGarage = Garage()
myGarage.id = 1
myGarage.carStored = teslaCar

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(myGarage, update: true)
}
```

... will the write cascade, and also save the `teslaCar` to the `Realm` as well as `myGarage`?

*The Realm Swift write docs: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested it in one of the Realm sample apps to be absolutely sure. Yes, if you set an object as a linked object of another Realm object, both will be added to Realm in the next write transaction.